# Is it a good idea to run parts of an object in multiple threads?

Tags: c++

Lets assume that we have 3 objects.

```cpp
class Skin {
public:
    Skin() {}
    virtual ~Skin() {}

    virtual void onUpdateSkin() {}
};

class Bones {
public:
    Bones() {}
    virtual ~Bones() {}

    virtual void onUpdateBones() {}
};

class Personality {
public:
    Personality() {}
    virtual ~Personality() {}

    virtual void onUpdatePersonality() {}
};
```

These three objects are used by 3 different systems which are running on different threads. Lets call them,

1. Appearance System - uses the Skin object(s)
2. Structural System - uses the Bones object(s)
3. Behavior System - uses the Personality object(s)

And now lets make an object out of these three objects.

```cpp
class Human final : public Skin, public Bones, public Personality {
public:
    Human() {}
    ~Human() {}

    virtual void onUpdateSkin() override final 
    {
        ...
    }

    virtual void onUpdateBones() override final 
    {
        ...
    }

    virtual void onUpdatePersonality() override final 
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

And then we create an instance to the 'Human"' object and we submit it to the system. Each system calls the method(s) which it has control over.

```cpp
// The appearance system
{
    ...

    for(Skin* pSkin : pSkins)
        pSkin->onUpdateSkin();

    ...
}

// The structural system
{
    ...

    for(Bones* pStructure : pStructures)
        pStructure->onUpdateBones();

    ...
}

// The behaviour system
{
    ...

    for(Personality* pPersonality : pPersonalities)
        pPersonality->onUpdatePersonality();

    ...
}
```

And as far as i know, when you inherit data from another class, the parent class's data will be placed before/ on top of the object's own data in the memory layout.

**So my questions are,**

1. Since all the 3 systems are calling methods which are in one object asynchronously, and since these systems are accessing different parts of the memory block (as i have explained above assuming that its correct), will it lead to any performance issues, and/or any memory corruption issues?
2. Is this type of implementation cache friendly?

Thank you!

Comment: TL; DR; As for the question in the title: It depends. 1st make sure you're not running into race conditions. 2nd think twice if using threads would really give you an advantage in performance. 3rd There's no thing like _real time_ computing, you'll always have to check if the time gaps you can't avoid, will fit your requirements well. -- Just my 2¢

Comment: Two answer #2, this is not particularly cache friendly.  You are iterating over one type of component at a time (I'll call them A, B, and C), but your memory looks like ABCABCABC instead of AAABBBCCC.  Cache efficiency will be better if you have objects of the same type stored contiguously.